# How to read/write 3D+ arrays with JHDF5?

Tags: java, hdf5

I see no methods to write arrays with dimensions greater than 2 in [`IHDF5SimpleWriter`](http://svncisd.ethz.ch/doc/hdf5/hdf5-13.06/ch/systemsx/cisd/hdf5/IHDF5SimpleWriter.html)

Is it possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. As [its documentation](http://svncisd.ethz.ch/doc/hdf5/hdf5-13.06/ch/systemsx/cisd/hdf5/IHDF5SimpleWriter.html) states, an `IHDF5SimpleWriter` “…contains only the basic methods.”

If you need to do this you'll need to use the non-simple writer for your data type, such as the [IHDF5ByteWriter](http://svncisd.ethz.ch/doc/hdf5/hdf5-14.12/ch/systemsx/cisd/hdf5/IHDF5ByteWriter.html), and use one of the `createMDArray` methods. Good luck!